# Subgroup generated by an element of infinite order in a compact group

Tags: lie-groups

Suppose one has a connected compact Lie group $K$, and an element $k\in K$ of infinite order. Then can the subgroup generated by $k$ be discrete?

I suspect the answer is no, but this suspicion is mostly based on the example of irrational rotations in $S^1$, where the powers of an irrational rotation have accumulation points and hence cannot form a discrete subgroup. But can this argument be adapted to get the result for a general compact connected Lie group?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I suspect they meant discrete in the _topological_ sense.

Comment: Yes I meant in the subspace topology inherited from $K$.

Comment: You are correct. Every Lie group is a manifold and hence metrizable, and for metrizable spaces compactness is equivalent to limit point compactness.

Comment: Thank you Travis. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: A discrete subgroup of a compact Lie group is finite, so the answer is no.

Comment: Right, I guess you could use the fact that a discrete subgroup of a Hausdorff group is always closed to get that.